# UI does not change after change selected option by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to be able to change the selected option by jQuery by $(".classname").val("0").
However, even though I can change the selected option, UI does not reflect the selected option right now... I am quite stuck on what is wrong. If I does this with only jQuery library (i.e. include only this library), it works. I mean my project includes a lot of other javascript also. I don't if they affected.

For example,

```
alert($('.test').val()); //I get "1"
$('.test').val("0");
alert($('.test').val()); //I get "0"
```

In the above example, looks that jQuery actually changed the selected option because .val() returns the "0" (i.e. selected option) But, UI shows still "1" as the selected option. I have tried another ways in the Internet. But, UI does not refresh the selected option.
Is there anyone who has had the same experience?

```
<select class="test"  style="font-size:12px;">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

jquery-1.9.1.js is used.

Comment: you are not talking about <select> aren't you ?

Comment: It is working for me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSYax/2/)

Comment: if it is <select> you are talking about, try $(".test>option:selected").val() to get what you have selected or set the value of it

Comment: Hi, thanks. actually, I am using <select>. I edited the quest

Comment: Can you post a fiddle as your `html` doesn't suggest that first suggested value is "1". so it makes me think that there is another factor involved that might be messing with it.

Comment: Hi Twocode, I tried your one. And, I get "0". So, looks that "0" is selected correctly

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/gYD9a/1/ There must be another conflict. You might try checking your browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: Actually, it was working before. So, I guess that there might be some error? Actually, the code is very big. So, It is quite hard to find where is wrong. But, only this select functionality does not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work? replace someValue with which one you want to switch to...

```
$('.test').find('option[value='+someValue+']').prop('selected',true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked! Um. But, it was working. So, I would have to think of checking codes. But, it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood you question before. Do you want to trigger the select box so that the changed value is reflected on UI ? May this works :

```
 $(".test").val(1).trigger("select");  // Change and trigger to '1'
 $(".test").val(0).trigger("select");  // Change and trigger to '0'
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion. This was not working-. But, I imagine this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a UI framework like jQuery UI or jQueryMobile? Since it works when you only include jQuery I definitely think the issue is caused by one of the other javascript libraries you are including.

Comment: Hi thanks, I got make it work by the jsmartfo's suggestion. But, as you say, there would be some issue. So, I think I have to look at my codes

Answer (score 0):

Somehow @jsmartfo 's solution didn't work for me. Possible reason can be newer version of jquery UI as this is old question.

However, following snippet works for me.

```
$('#myElemendId').val(valueToSet).selectmenu('refresh');
```